# Write a test for getServerSideProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to write a test for a server-side function, asserting whether it returns the correct data, if the user has permissions:

```
export const getServerSideProps = getServerSidePropsWrapper(async ({ locale, query }, { accessToken }) => {
    const { shopId, groupId } = query as IQuery;

    const [userResponse, customerGroupResponse] = await Promise.all([
        getUser(locale as string, accessToken as string),
        getCustomerGroup(
            locale as string,
            accessToken,
            shopId,
            groupId
        ) as Promise<Response>
    ]);
    let customerGroup = {} as IResponse<ICustomerGroup, null>;

    if (userResponse.ok && customerGroupResponse.ok) {
        const user = await userResponse.json() as IResponse<IUserInput, null>;
        customerGroup = await customerGroupResponse.json() as IResponse<ICustomerGroup, null>;

        if (!user.data?.permissions.includes('canUpdateTargetGroup')) {
            return {
                ok: false,
                status: statusCodes.unauthorized
            };
        }
    }
    //this statement needs to be covered
    return {
        ok: true,
        status: statusCodes.ok,
        data: {
            customerGroup: customerGroup.data,
            locale
        }
    };
}, ['customerGroup', 'common', 'validations']);
```

I need to test the last `return` statement. This is the test I came up with:

```
it('should return customer group data, if user has permissions', async () => {
    const result = await getServerSideProps(serverSideProps) as never as { props: { customerGroup: ICustomerGroup, locale: string } };

    //returns undefined
    expect(result.props.customerGroup).toEqual(customerGroup);
    expect(result.props.locale).toEqual('en_US');
});
```

When I run the test, `result.props.customerGroup` returns `undefined`. How should I go about testing the last `return` statment?